Consider the function $\phi(x)=\ln x$ from $\mathbb R^+$ (under mult) to the group $\mathbb R$ (under add) . Prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.
Okay so I've proved all of the parts needed for an isomorphism except to show that $\phi(x)$ is onto. How do I go about doing that? I know that you start by assuming that $y \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and that we want to end up proving that for each of those ys there exists and x in \mathbb{R}. But how do I get there?

Hint.  Given $y=\ln x$, can you solve for $x$?

Don't abbreviate words. Under mult? Under add? The internet is big enough for full words, and your goal should be not to confuse the volunteers you are asking help from.

Many facts about the natural logarithm are easily deduced from facts about its inverse function $e^x$.

This has been asked before, I bet.

IIRC this is a exercise in Rotman's group theory book.
